# How to build dockerfile with multiple dependent assemblies to asp.net core webapi, as i am getting docker build error?

Tags: docker

**1. MY Docker file is below.**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestAPI"
RUN dotnet build "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestAPI.dll"]
```

**2. My solution structure is below.**
[Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMdE9.png)

**3.Folder structure**

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk2E3.png)

**4.Error I am getting is below:**

[Docker build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua1jO.png)

Comment: any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are only copying the `TestaApi` project to your image. Maybe you should copy the whole solution. Have you defined your `Testlibrary` as a project dependency in your solution? Check your solution's build order, if `Testlibrary` is built before `TestApi`

Comment: Can you please update the dockerfile which is mentioned above.Also I have checked the build order as TestAPI has a dependency over TestLibrary so the buildorder is      TestLibrary->TestAPI. You can see the solution structure from the attached image.

Comment: Hi, your question would be easier to read with actual text instead of images.